# php ssh connection phpseclib

Tags: php, linux, ssh, xampp, phpseclib

System: Linux
Server: XAMPP
Goal:
ssh-connection to a server (later: doing some stuff on this server, not part of this question)

Test-Code:

```
 <?php  
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/home/myusername');
    include('Net/SSH2.php'); 
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('123.45.6.78'); 
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) { 
    exit('Login Failed'); 
    }else{ 
    echo "connected".'<br>'; 
    echo $ssh->exec('whoami').'<br>';
    echo $ssh->exec('hostname')).'<br>';
    }   
    ?>
```

Output:

    connected
    (M4300-28G-PoE+) >
    (M4300-28G-PoE+) >

Problem:
I do not get any errors (neither in the output of the website (see above) nor in /opt/lampp/logs/error_logs), so:
Question(s):
Why am I not getting any output (user, hostname)? 
Are there other/better ways to check whether I am properly connected?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you *are* getting output. `(M4300-28G-PoE+) >` is the output you're getting and you're getting it for both of the commands you're trying to run.

M4300-28G-PoE+ is a [NetGear switch](https://www.netgear.com/business/products/switches/managed/M4300-28G-PoE-plus-1000W-PSU.aspx). Switches are fairly notorious for not having full SSH implementations.

My guess: if you want to run commands you'll have to use phpseclib's [interactive commands](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive):

```
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n"); // note the "\n"
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
```